# libudev1 (jammy-updates) removes many packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, udev, 22.04

Installing `libudev1 249.11-0ubuntu3.1` from jammy-updates will remove many packages. What could be the cause?

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

# apt install libudev1
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bolt busybox-initramfs cryptsetup finalrd fwupd-signed
  gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 initramfs-tools-bin klibc-utils libappstream4
  libarchive13 libatasmart4 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2
  libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2
  libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libdw1 libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 libfwupd2
  libfwupdplugin5 libgcab-1.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libgpgme11 libgstreamer1.0-0
  libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2 libisns0 libjcat1 libjson-glib-1.0-0
  libjson-glib-1.0-common libklibc libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libmm-glib0
  libnetplan0 libnspr4 libnss3 libopeniscsiusr libpackagekit-glib2-18
  libparted-fs-resize0 libplymouth5 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libsgutils2-2 libsmbios-c2 libstemmer0d libtcl8.6
  libudisks2-0 liburcu8 libvolume-key1 libxmlb2 python3-software-properties
  sg3-utils squashfs-tools tcl tcl8.6 usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cloud-init cloud-initramfs-copymods cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf
  cryptsetup-initramfs dbus-user-session friendly-recovery fwupd
  initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core kpartx libnss-systemd libpam-systemd
  libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu0 libtss2-sys1 libtss2-tcti-cmd0
  libtss2-tcti-device0 libtss2-tcti-mssim0 libtss2-tcti-swtpm0 mdadm
  modemmanager multipath-tools netplan.io open-iscsi overlayroot packagekit
  packagekit-tools pkexec plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1
  polkitd sg3-utils-udev snapd software-properties-common tpm-udev
  ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-server ubuntu-standard udev udisks2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libudev1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 41 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 76.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 125 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]


Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libudev1 amd64 249.11-0ubuntu3.1 [76.9 kB]
Fetched 76.9 kB in 1s (79.6 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 63758 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cloud-init (22.1-14-g2e17a0d6-0ubuntu1~22.04.5) ...
Removing ubuntu-server (1.481) ...
Removing cloud-initramfs-copymods (0.47ubuntu1) ...
Removing cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf (0.47ubuntu1) ...
Removing cryptsetup-initramfs (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing snapd (2.55.3+22.04) ...
Stopping snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.service
Stopping unit snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.service
Waiting until unit snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.service is stopped [attempt 1]
snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.service is stopped.
Stopping snap.lxd.activate.service
Stopping unit snap.lxd.activate.service
Waiting until unit snap.lxd.activate.service is stopped [attempt 1]
snap.lxd.activate.service is stopped.
Stopping snap.lxd.daemon.service
Stopping unit snap.lxd.daemon.service
Waiting until unit snap.lxd.daemon.service is stopped [attempt 1]
snap.lxd.daemon.service is stopped.
Stopping snap.lxd.user-daemon.service
Stopping unit snap.lxd.user-daemon.service
Waiting until unit snap.lxd.user-daemon.service is stopped [attempt 1]
snap.lxd.user-daemon.service is stopped.
grep: /etc/systemd/system/snap.lxd.workaround.service: No such file or directory
Skipping non-snapd systemd unit snap.lxd.workaround.service
Stopping snap.lxd.daemon.unix.socket
Stopping unit snap.lxd.daemon.unix.socket
Waiting until unit snap.lxd.daemon.unix.socket is stopped [attempt 1]
snap.lxd.daemon.unix.socket is stopped.
Stopping snap.lxd.user-daemon.unix.socket
Stopping unit snap.lxd.user-daemon.unix.socket
Waiting until unit snap.lxd.user-daemon.unix.socket is stopped [attempt 1]
snap.lxd.user-daemon.unix.socket is stopped.
Warning: Stopping snapd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  snapd.socket
Removing dbus-user-session (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
Removing friendly-recovery (0.2.42) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/40-force-partuuid.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
GRUB_FORCE_PARTUUID is set, will attempt initrdless boot
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-1004-aws
Found initrd image: /boot/microcode.cpio /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-1004-aws
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
done
Removing fwupd (1.7.5-3) ...
Removing multipath-tools (0.8.8-1ubuntu1) ...
Warning: Stopping multipath-tools.service, but it can still be activated by:
  multipathd.socket
Removing sg3-utils-udev (1.46-1build1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing overlayroot (0.47ubuntu1) ...
Removing initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
Removing initramfs-tools-core (0.140ubuntu13) ...
Removing kpartx (0.8.8-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libnss-systemd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3) ...
Checking NSS setup...
Removing ubuntu-standard (1.481) ...
Removing software-properties-common (0.99.22) ...
Removing packagekit-tools (1.2.5-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing packagekit (1.2.5-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing modemmanager (1.18.6-1) ...
Unknown option: runtime
Removing policykit-1 (0.105-33) ...
Removing pkexec (0.105-33) ...
Removing polkitd (0.105-33) ...
Removing libpam-systemd:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0:amd64 (3.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtss2-tcti-swtpm0:amd64 (3.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtss2-tcti-mssim0:amd64 (3.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtss2-sys1:amd64 (3.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtss2-tcti-cmd0:amd64 (3.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtss2-tcti-device0:amd64 (3.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing mdadm (4.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing ubuntu-minimal (1.481) ...
Removing netplan.io (0.104-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing netplan.io, directory '/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing netplan.io, directory '/etc/netplan' not empty so not removed
Removing open-iscsi (2.1.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Warning: Stopping iscsid.service, but it can still be activated by:
  iscsid.socket
Removing plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.5+git20211018-1ubuntu3) ...
Removing plymouth (0.9.5+git20211018-1ubuntu3) ...
Removing udisks2 (2.9.4-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing libtss2-mu0:amd64 (3.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing tpm-udev (0.6) ...
Removing udev (249.11-0ubuntu3) ...
(Reading database ... (Reading database ... 5%(Reading database ... 10%(Reading database ... 15%(Reading database ... 20%(Reading database ... 25%(Reading database ... 30%(Reading database ... 35%(Reading database ... 40%(Reading database ... 45%(Reading database ... 50%(Reading database ... 55%(Reading database ... 60%(Reading database ... 65%(Reading database ... 70%(Reading database ... 75%(Reading database ... 80%(Reading database ... 85%(Reading database ... 90%(Reading database ... 95%(Reading database ... 100%(Reading database ... 62205 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libudev1_249.11-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libudev1:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.1) over (249.11-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libudev1:amd64 (249.11-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
```

**Update**

### How to reproduce

Boot an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu cloud image.

- https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

In this case, use [ami-0ee8244746ec5d6d4](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-west-2#launchAmi=ami-0ee8244746ec5d6d4) (Zone=us-west-2, Release=20220420).

After logging in as the ubuntu user, become root and run `apt update`.

```
sudo -i
apt update
```

The package I want to install is `liblvm2-dev`, but it tries to remove `cloud-init`, `snapd`, `udev`, `ubuntu-standard` and many other packages.

```
apt install liblvm2-dev
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  cloud-init cloud-initramfs-copymods cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf cryptsetup-initramfs
  dbus-user-session friendly-recovery fwupd initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core kpartx
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu0 libtss2-sys1 libtss2-tcti-cmd0
  libtss2-tcti-device0 libtss2-tcti-mssim0 libtss2-tcti-swtpm0 mdadm modemmanager multipath-tools
  netplan.io open-iscsi overlayroot packagekit packagekit-tools pkexec plymouth
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1 polkitd sg3-utils-udev snapd software-properties-common
  tpm-udev ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-server ubuntu-standard udev udisks2
...
```

### Why try to remove so many packages?

The dependency chain from `liblvm2-dev` looks like this:

```
liblvm2-dev
Depends: liblvm2cmd2.03 (= 2.03.11-2.1ubuntu4), libdevmapper-dev

libdevmapper-dev
Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (= 2:1.02.175-2.1ubuntu4), libdevmapper-event1.02.1 (= 2:1.02.175-2.1ubuntu4), libudev-dev, libselinux1-dev

libudev-dev
Depends: libudev1 (= 249.11-0ubuntu3.1)
```

`libudev-dev` is not installed and tries to install the latest `249.11-0ubuntu3.1`, but the `libudev1` (`libudev-dev` depends) has an older version of `249.11-0ubuntu3` installed, causing some problems I imagine.

### What I want to know

I found a workaround that doing `apt install udev` or `apt upgrade` before `apt install liblvm2-dev`.

However, since `libudev-dev` is not installed either way, I think the same problem will occur when a new version `249.11-0ubuntu3.2` is released.

I am also concerned that other packages may cause the same problem.

That is why I am interested in knowing how to deal with the root cause of the problem.

Please let me know if there is anything else you need from me.

Comment: Why wasn't `libudev1` already installed? It is a dependency of `udev` which is a dependency of `ubuntu-mininal` so it should be installed in every jammy installation. In other words, what is the history behind this question? What did you do to your system?

Comment: libudev1 is installed.

```
# apt policy libudev1
libudev1:
  Installed: 249.11-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 249.11-0ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
     249.11-0ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 249.11-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: OK, so you are having a problem *updating* it, not *installing* it. How about the rest of the question? What did you do to your system? Hiding info isn't going to help fix your system. I just ran updates on a jammy system and it went fine, so something is off in your system.

Comment: Your output clearly states that those packages are *already* eligible for autoremoval, regardless of any package actions you propose now. You *previously* removed some key package(s). Either go through the list and apt-mark "manual" the packages you want to keep (see `man apt-mark`), or else review the dependencies of the packages that you already removed and restore the key package(s).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have added how to reproduce and my thought.